# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Hangs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I'm having this problem for about a month. First I think that was Memory, since desenv.exe was using almost 1GB, so I've upgraded to 8GB. Then it could be extensions, and with all disabled and even uninstalled it continues. I even reinstalled my Windows 7 to make sure that isn't any external source.
Since the problem started with an old website made in VB.NET, I suposed that was the migration.
Today I was working in another website C# project and the problem returned. The last try was to change the framework version from 4 to 3.5 and nothing.

One thing that the two project have in common is that they have a lot of files. Realy lot. Booth of them are eCommece project and they have too many files. But I can't do anything abount that.

My VS hangs everytime, when editing, showing intellisense, saving file, doing nothing...
This problem does not exists when I used the same projects in VS2008.
Anyone knows what can I do about that?

Answer (score 1):

Found a workarround.
I have migrated my c# project to an Web Application and the freezes stopped.
I belive that the VS was trying to compile my website on every edit I made to my files, since my desenv.exe proccess was getting High every time it freezes and when about to release it back comes the csc.exe at Hige CPU for a moment.